# Grouping observations from multiple tests

Tags: r, plyr

I've been working at this long enough to see that a) there is probably an easy way to do this, and b) a fresh set of eyes will probably see it before I do. So here goes..

Two or more tests were performed to classify items into two or more categories. We hypothesize that a more reliable measurement would come from using a combination of classifiers. To test this, we need to see how predictions perform in concert with each other, rather than just aggregating results from individual tests. A first step in this analysis is simulating measurements coming from all the tests simultaneously by grouping test results into observations.

```
set.seed(103)
test1 <- data.frame(trueClass=rep(c('A','B','C'), times=c(2,3,4)), score=rpois(9,10))
test2 <- data.frame(trueClass=rep(c('A','B','C'), times=c(3,3,3)), score=rpois(9,5))
test3 <- data.frame(trueClass=rep(c('A','B','C'), times=c(4,2,3)), score=rpois(9,2))

all.data <- list(test1=test1, test2=test2, test3=test3)
```

We define an observation as an ordered triple containing one `score` from each test of the same `trueClass`. Ideally, in the end we will have a tidy `data.frame` that looks like

```
>observation.df
  test1 test2 test3 trueClass
1    11     6     2         A
2    16     4     4         A
3     6     9     2         B
4   ...
```

The difficulty is that the number of observations is limited by the lowest number of representations of a class in a test. In this case, the minimums are

```
mins <- c(A=2, B=2, C=3)
```

So, I would like to sample 2 test results from each test with `trueClass = A`, 2 with `trueClass = B`, and 3 with `trueClass = C` and store them in `observation.df`.

Obviously the function creating the observations needs to learn the names of the tests and the classes from `all.data`.

```
test.names <- names(all.data)
class.names <- unique(as.vector(sapply(all.data, function(i) i$trueClass)))
```

To get the number of each class to sample:

```
library(plyr)
count.table <- laply(all.data, function(i) table(i$trueClass))
mins <- apply(count.table, 2, min)
```

It seems to me that there should be a fairly straightforward way to go from here (probably using `by` or a `plyr` function), but I haven't succeeded in anything other than complicating the matter.

Comment: `test.names` returns NULL since you didn't give them names.

Comment: @DWin I edited the code to fix that error. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rather convoluted answer potentially, but it gets the job done.

```
cutlist <- lapply(all.data,
  function(x)
  do.call(rbind,
    sapply(names(mins), function(y) {
       subs <- x[x$trueClass==y,]
       subs[sample(1:nrow(subs),mins[y]),]
       },
    simplify=FALSE
    )
  )
)

cbind(cutlist[[1]]["trueClass"] , sapply(cutlist,"[[","score",simplify=TRUE))
```

Result:

```
    trueClass  1 2 3
A.1         A  7 8 2
A.2         A 10 5 5
B.5         B  8 4 4
B.4         B  4 9 2
C.7         C  6 3 3
C.9         C  7 8 0
C.8         C  8 8 3
```

Comment: When I try running what you wrote, I run into the problem that `cutlist[[1]]` is a list with elements `A, B, C`, so `cutlist[[1]]["trueClass"] = NULL`.

Comment: @D_Watkins - I think you may have missed my edit - I accidentally copied an early version which was missing the `do.call(rbind,...)` - try the code exactly as above now.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this? (this is a quick-and-dirty approach)

```
  library(plyr)
  set.seed(103)
  test1 <- data.frame(trueClass=rep(c('A','B','C'), times=c(2,3,4)), score=rpois(9,10))
  test2 <- data.frame(trueClass=rep(c('A','B','C'), times=c(3,3,3)), score=rpois(9,5))
  test3 <- data.frame(trueClass=rep(c('A','B','C'), times=c(4,2,3)), score=rpois(9,2))
  all.data <- list(test1, test2, test3)
  num<-list(1,2,3)
  kk<-Map(function(x) ddply(all.data[[x]],.(trueClass),summarize,sam1=unique(ifelse(trueClass %in% c("A","B"),sample(score,2),sample(score,3)))),num)



 > kk
[[1]]
  trueClass sam1
1         A   10
2         A    7
3         B    8
4         B    5
5         C   12
6         C    7
7         C    6

[[2]]
  trueClass sam1
1         A    5
2         A    8
3         B    4
4         B    9
5         C    8
6         C    3

[[3]]
  trueClass sam1
1         A    0
2         A    2
3         B    4
4         B    2
5         C    3
6         C    0



kkk<-ldply(kk)
kkk$test<-with(kkk,rep(c("test1","test2","test3"),c(nrow(kk[[1]]),nrow(kk[[2]]),nrow(kk[[3]]))))
> kkk
   trueClass sam1  test
1          A    7 test1
2          A   10 test1
3          B    8 test1
4          B    5 test1
5          C   12 test1
6          C    8 test1
7          C    7 test1
8          A    8 test2
9          A    5 test2
10         B    9 test2
11         B   12 test2
12         C    8 test2
13         C    3 test2
14         A    2 test3
15         A    5 test3
16         B    2 test3
17         B    4 test3
18         C    3 test3
19         C    0 test3
```

You can use `reshape` to get what you want.

Comment: Isn't `C` meant to have 3 observations not 2?

Comment: @ thelatemail: Thanks.I have updated that. But, I hope there should be neat approach.

Comment: This is pretty close - from the look of things, `merge(kk)` should return the `observation.df` I was looking for. Something subtle is going on with the `summarise` call though, because we get 3 observations of `C` in `test1` and only 2 in the other two. The call to create `kk` can be simplified by using `lapply(all.data, function(x) ddply(x, ...`, although using `Map` is cool.

Comment: `Map` is same as `lapply` with one input. So, you will get the same result.

Comment: @Metrics - `Map` is actually `mapply(...,SIMPLIFY=FALSE)`, but it will work similarly to `lapply` with the order of the arguments  reversed.

Comment: @ thelatemail: Exactly, but page [here](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Functionals) suggests  using `Map` instead of `mapply`.